# Difference between application and module pipelines in Nancy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nancy

I have seen in the documentation of [Nancy](http://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/), sometimes these two are referred distinctively.

And also is there a difference in the Before/After hooks of these two pipelines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [module-](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-before-and-after-module-hooks) and [application](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Application-Before%2C-After-and-OnError-pipelines) pipelines are explained in detail in the wiki.

It's basically hooks which are executed before and after route execution on a global (application pipelines) and per-module basis. Here's an example:

If a route is resolved to a module called `FooModule`, the pipelines will be invoked as follows:

- Application Before Pipeline
- FooModule Before Pipeline
- FooModule Route Handler
- FooModule After Pipeline
- Application After Pipeline

The difference between the before- and after pipelines is that in the before pipeline, you have the possibility to "short circuit" the request handling. I.e. you can return a response, which will the be returned directly to the user agent, without even invoking a potential route handler.